# JIRA Remaining estimate

Tags: jira, scrum, time-estimation, scrumboard

JIRA  User Story Time Tracking

I recently adopted JIRA as a Scrum agile development tool.

This is my scenario:

- Scrum board
- Estimation Statistic: Original Time Estimate
- Time Tracking: Remaining Estimate and Time Spent
- Our Product Owner populates BackLog with  “User Story” issues
- Our team estimates each “User Story” so we fill “Original Estimate” field in the “User Story”

Once all  “User Stories” are dropped to current sprint, we start the sprint.

At this point, only “User Story” issues exists in the current sprint.
Then, the development team starts working.

So, a team member takes the first user story issue and breaks it down into several sub tasks (depending on user story complexity).

Once a sub task is completed, the team member logs work into the sub task “Time Spent” field.

**What do we expect?**

We expect, “Remaining time” in “User Story time tracking” is updated by the following formula:

```
[Remaining Estimate] = [Original Estimate] – ( Sum([ work log ]) )
```

Where *Sum([ work log ])* is the sum of “all work logged in all subtasks” plus “work log in user story”

**What we got**

Remaining is ONLY updated with “work log in user story” even when “Include sub-tasks” is checked

Is there any method or workaround to use JIRA to fit our needs?

Example:

1. Create User Story Issue “User Story 1” and estimate it (Original Estimate): 1 week
2. Create subtask “Subtask 1”
3. Create subtask “Subtask 2”
4. Log work in Subtask 1: 1 day
5. Log work un Subtask 2: 1 day
6. Refresh “User Story 1” issue time tracking

Time Tracking
Remaining : 1 week

When actually the team has worked 2 days!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is a well known [Jira Issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSW-9167)
It's a very old issue, and I'm surprised that Atlassian does not react to this.
Some users found a workaround (if you have installed Jira on your own server, not onDemand) : [creating a scripted custom field](https://riada.se/estimate-your-sub-tasks-in-jira-agile/), but I didn't try it